# Hosted IIS ASP.NET MVC Windows Authentication mix with No domain account

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, appdomain

It seems to be an easy problem.
I want to write intranet application hosted on IIS server with ASP.NET MVC using Windows Authentication but with some little confused logic.
I have to get domain user name to managed them inside another intranet application.

If user is logged to workstation in domain works fine, works automatically, but I want to allow local account to go to application and promp some login page with external database login logic and go ahead.

how can I do this, can I connect to hosted on IIS application and manage two different levels of application ?!?

Comment: Perhaps you need something like ADFS

Comment: You mean Active Directory Federation Services ? I read about adfs and I think that's not what i want.

Comment: I wanna host on IIS app with windows authentication and get auto login, or redirect to another app when using account out of domain.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought you wanted to allow web-based logins to the app when the user was logged in from other non-domain accounts, not redirect somewhere else entirely. If you just want to redirect, maybe you can change how IIS behaves when it cannot authenticate the Windows user - normally it issues a 401 challenge and the user gets a chance to type their password manually. Perhaps if that fails you can then redirect to your other website.

Comment: if outside the domain network it should redirect to login page without windows credential prompt is possible to do that ? i allways have promp windows in browser

Comment: yes if you use something like ADFS or OAuth then you can do things like that